# How to return data from a promise response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

What is the correct way to return data from a Promise? I have the following code:

```
const axios = require("axios").default;

async function getApiData(pathName: string, locale: string) {
    const {axiosRequestUrl} = getApiVars(pathName, locale);

    const axiosClient = axios.create({
        baseURL: process.env.CONTENT_DOMAIN,
        proxy: false
    })

    return await axiosClient.get(axiosRequestUrl);
}

export default function getPageData() {
    getApiData('shared-content', 'en-us')
        .then((data) => {
            return data;
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            // log error here
        })
}
```

but if I try to use `getPageData` from a component I end up with a `void` function that does not return anything, why? What I am missing here?

Comment: The Promise runs asynchronously. The correct way to return data from a Promise is to return the Promise itself and await it to access the results.

Comment: `getPageData` does not return anything

Answer (score -1):

At the very least, your `getPageData` function should itself be an `async` function (for clarity in code readability), which would return the promise returned by the `getApiData` call.

e.g.

```
export default async function getPageData() {
    return getApiData('shared-content', 'en-us');
}
```

Two further hints:

- You will need to resolve this promise in order to read the data.
- You can decide to do the error handling here on higher in the call hierarchy.

Rules of thumb:

- an `async` function is just a function that returns a `Promise` object.
- a promise only returns actual data when resolved (with `await` or `.then()`).

Comment: Using an `async` function without utilizing the `await` keyword is pretty useless.

Comment: It adds clarity in code readability by making it obvious that we're in an asynchronous context.